# Do sockets automatically close themselves when garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I create a `net.Socket` that is connected, and then delete all references to it so that it can be garbage collected, but I don't manually close it, will it automatically be closed?

Comment: As best I know, nodejs will close a FileHandle object when it's eligible for GC as the documentation explains (though with a process warning), but I do not think it will close a socket.  You could certainly devise a bit of a test where you open a socket to a server and then clear all references to it. making sure there aren't any event handlers listening for anything and then watch the other end of the socket to see if you get a close or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodejs does not automatically close sockets when your reference to the socket is eligible for garbage collection.  I have verified this with a test app that makes a simple TCP connection to a server and then nulls the reference to the socket I just connected and then uses an interval timer doing nothing but outputting to the console to keep the nodejs process alive.

When I watch the socket on the server, it is never closed - it is just kept open so even though the client socket reference is eligible for GC by virtue of no Javascript references to it retained, the socket connection is not closed.  This is true even when I do `socket.unref()`.

In a similar test with a `FileHandle` object, it was apparently garbage collected and the file descriptor was closed, though it emitted a process warning when doing so as this is not supposed to be a normal way of closing files.  Here's the warning I got:

```
(node:29520) Warning: Closing file descriptor 3 on garbage collection
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:29520) [DEP0137] DeprecationWarning: Closing a FileHandle object on garbage
    collection is deprecated. Please close FileHandle objects explicitly using 
    FileHandle.prototype.close(). In the future, an error will be thrown if a file 
    descriptor is closed during garbage collection.
```

And, this behavior is documented for FileHandle objects.